# TFS 2013 fails on second build

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

I have bizarre thing happening with my TFS 2013 server. The first build fines, but then subsequent builds keep failing with this message. I have to delete the build definition and recreate it and then melodrama repeats. After creating build definition the first build is always successful. Any ideas?

Exception Message: API resource location 225f7195-f9c7-4d14-ab28-a83f7ff77e1f is not registered on http://tfsserver:8081/tfs/mycollection. (type VssResourceNotFoundException)
Exception Stack Trace:    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpClientBase.d__1c.MoveNext()

Comment: Which version of TFS are you using? I think this was fixed in Update 4...

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to delete cache folder located under the service account that you choose to run Team Foundation Server.

C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\NetworkService\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation\5.0\Cache\

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem, first build worked fine, every subsequent build failed, running TFS 2013 (Update-4). Clearing the cache folder didn't solve the problem. But after upgrading to Update-5, the TFS-build worked again as expected.